# Product Quantity Stock Not decrease When Order is Placed

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, admin, inventory

I have import several configurable product with mag mi and its working fine except for inventory management.

When i placed an order newly imported product quantity not decrease.However if i create a new configurable product and its associate product its working fine.

configuration setting in System-configuration->Catalog->inventory.

1)Decrease Stock When Order is Placed ->Yes.

2)Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled->Yes.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

System -> Configuration -> Catalog|Inventory -> Decrease Stock When Order is Placed

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/cataloginventory